# Camel file component for network disks

Tags: file, tomcat, service, apache-camel, network-drive

I need to save file to network drive using system service for Apache tomcat and get all the time error:

```
Exception: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: u:\xxx.txt
```

My route sample:

```
<route id="myRoute">
        <from uri="quartz:myQuartz?cron=0+0+*+?+*+MON-FRI"/> 
        <camel:doTry> 
            <bean method="getData" ref="myService"/>
            <marshal ref="bindyFixedDataformat"/>
            <to uri="file:u:?fileName=xxx.txt&amp;autoCreate=false&amp;fileExist=Append"/>
            <to uri="file://c:/XXX/files?fileName=xxx-${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.txt"/>
            <camel:bean method="setProcessed" ref="myService"/>
        <camel:doCatch>
            <exception>java.io.IOException</exception>
            <camel:log message="Network drive (U:) is not available, please renew connection!" loggingLevel="ERROR"/>
            <camel:bean method="setFailed" ref="myService"/>
        </camel:doCatch>
        <camel:doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <camel:log message="Unexpected error has occured!" loggingLevel="ERROR" />
            <camel:bean method="setFailed" ref="myService"/>
        </camel:doCatch>
        </camel:doTry>
    </route>
```

'U' disk is the mapped network disk. But the same route with my second partition disk 'D' file creates successfully.

I'm generating WAR file and run it with Local System Service by Apache Tomcat.

Interesting, that before service, when I run the same project with eclipse by maven - copying to U disk was happening successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The local system service user probably can't see your mapped drive 'U'. Solution: use UNC paths.

Note that the user running Tomcat will need permission to access the network path - often a local system service user won't have. In that case you can run Tomcat as a user who does have permission, i.e. by changing the user in the 'Log on' tab of the service.

Comment: If I change to this:
<to uri="file:\\1.255.255.1\directory?fileName=xxx.txt&amp;autoCreate=false&amp;fileExist=Append"/>

I get the same error
Exception: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: \\1.255.255.1\directory\xxx.txt

Also if I change in Log on for service same user to what are permissions to this network drive - result the same. :(

Comment: So, can you open \\1.255.255.1\directory if you type/paste this into Windows Explorer when logged in as that user?

Comment: Yes! I can even create, change and delete there files.

Comment: For more information, see this discussion on the Camel mailing lists: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Windows-network-share-td4661277.html